# LibGDX Timer doesn't start after game resumed on android

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx

I'm creating 2 timers in my code. One is the logic timer that updates the logic every 0.017 seconds:

```
logicTimer = new Timer();
    logicTimer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateLogic();
        }
    }, 0f, timePerProcessing);
```

And the other one is for generating obstacles every 3 seconds:

```
meteoroidTimer = new Timer();
    meteoroidTimer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            generateMeteoroids();
        }
    },1f,3f);
```

When I pause my game and resume afterwards, my logic timer still works but my obstacle timer doesn't. I thought it was because I use a Random object in my method that I call in the timer, but I tried with a simple:

```
System.out.println("It is showing");
```

and it still doesn't resume.

My code for pause and resume:

```
@Override
public void pause(){
    meteoroidTimer.stop();
    logicTimer.stop();
}

@Override
public void resume(){
    meteoroidTimer.start();
    logicTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about pausing the game, or pausing the activity? Those could be two very different things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to android, but It's when I press the button on the right of my phone that pauses the game and shows me other open apps.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask, why are you using a timer (which uses a separate thread to the render thread) instead of tracking delta time and triggering these actions on the render thread?

Comment: Because I know that the render method is dependent of hardware frequency. That's why I'm using a timer to get the exact time elapsed. I don't know how to do it other way like with the delta time.

Comment: This sounds like a known [bug](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2274) in `libgdx` that has since been [solved](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2305). Are you sure you are using the latest `libgdx` release?

Comment: I'm using the latest libgdx release. I just deleted the methods stop() and start() from both timers in resume() and pause() and it works -.-

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use the timer.stop and star on resume because when you leave the app libgdx stops rendering/updating anyway so your timers wont be updated anyway.